# Trying to create a Flutter App Bar sub menu widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an app I am builidng in flutter and I want to achieve a similar design that exists in Quora. It it appears to be a sub menu underneath the AppBar and it scrolls horizontally. Is there anything the exists widget wise in flutter that I can use?

I am attaching a screen shot, its the white menu that starts with "For You"

[image: Sub Menu]

Comment: Are you looking for [TabBar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html) ?

Comment: @RémiRousselet that looks like it’s it! Thank u

Comment: What you have tried before creating this view?

Comment: I havent tried anything but the Tab bar thusfar, Tab bar seems troublesome to style though.